Get reel views from the Instagram Graph API
I am trying to use the Instagram Graph API to get the view count or some similar metric of Instagram Reels for a business account.
I have successfully connected to the API and can retrieve basic media information, but I am unable to find get the reel views or any similar metric based on what the documentation suggests. Currently I am facing permission errors and more even if I request stories for my own profile.
I have set all the permissions the documentation suggests.
Did anyone manage to get a similar metric successfully?
Any suggestions?
